# Automatic CSV import into Outlook

Tags: python, csv, import, outlook, foxpro

I have a daily-generated CSV file containing contact data which I want load entries into an Outlook contact file (overwriting the file each time, not appending).  I know I can import the CSV file manually, but that's a pain to do every day.  Has anyone any ideas how I can automate the process (eg. by running a scheduled batch or exe file)?  I am proficient in Python and Visual Foxpro, so if a programming solution is required, either of these languages would be preferable.

Also, I want to ensure that the imported fields are in the correct order.  Where can I find a default field-mapping list for the contact file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can import the file manually, you can certainly automate it. With VFP, you'd create an instance of Outlook, instantiate the namespace, and then call on whatever the method is that imports the CSV.

```
oOutlook = CREATEOBJECT("Outlook.Application")
oNS = oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
* You'll probably have to drill in and grab a reference
* to some object before calling whatever the method is
```

One issue with automating Outlook is that it likes to protect itself from code touching some things and I wouldn't be surprised if Contact records are among those. If this is for your own personal use, you could turn that protection off. The specifics depend on the version. In Outlook 2010, it's File | Options, then Trust Center, then Programmatic Access.

Once you've got code that works, build an EXE, and use the Windows Task Scheduler to run it daily.

Tamar

Comment: Thanks Tamar, that's the sort of solution I was looking for.  I will check-out the programmatic access and see how I get on.  Regards.

Comment: Hi Tamar - I am back on this project now and would like to take it further.  You mentioned "You'll probably have to drill in and grab a reference to some object before calling whatever the method is".  Do you know any resources where I can find the appropriate Outlook object methods or properties?  Thanks.

Comment: You didn't say what version of Outlook, but this should get you started: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee861520.aspx. If you're using Outlook 2003 or earlier, the VBA Help that's part of Outlook Help is very good.

Answer (score 0):

There is a csv module in Python: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html
It allows you to handle csv files painlessly.

However, since you didn't specify the format of the Outlook file, there is nothing more I can do for you. You should clarify how the output should look like, maybe with a good example, and then we yould work on it.

Comment: Turion - thanks for the reply.  I don't know what format Outlook stores its contact data in (just shows my ignorance of the subject!).  I'll check it out and report back.  I am aware of the Python csv module, and eventually I might have to resort to using it, but I was hoping for a solution which automatically does what the manual import does(perhaps from the command line or using OLE), which does not require knowledge of the stored format, only the format in which the imported data is presented.  Regards,

Comment: "which automatically does what the manual import does"
Outlook is not Open Source, so there is no way to "use" its functions.
(Fourtyseventh advantage of open source software over proprietary software)